# Two ocilloscopes producing different readings

Tags: oscilloscope

Our Fluke keypad is non-functioning (tried to get it repaired but the repair service said no) so I bought a new Rigol DS1202.

We are trying to measure a pulsed signal from an encoder. The Fluke shows that the when the prox gets off target, the signal goes back to 0 volts with a very sharp 90 degree wave. When we look at the same encoder, at the same speed on the Rigol, it is showing a rounded off wave when the prox goes off target. We have the Rigol channel 1 and channel 2 set to 1x probe scale, and the actual probes are also set to 1x.

Would this be user error or do we have a setting somewhere in the scope that needs to be changed?

[image]

[image]

Here is a photo of the reading with the probes in 10x:

[image]

Comment: Can you use 10X attenuator probes on the RIGOL 'scope? Compare rise/fall times with the 1X probe measurement that you've shown us. If you use 10X attenuator probes, ensure that they are properly calibrated for rise/fall time using a known-good square wave generator. Many 'scope provide a "CAL output" square wave source for this purpose.

Comment: What Glen is getting at, is that it could be the 1X probes.  In general, 1X probes are seldom used; 10X (or even 100X) probes are generally more useful.

Comment: What about the probes? Same probes in both cases? Or different probes? If different probes, what happens when you swap the probes from one scope to the other? If different probes, what happens if you leave both sets of probes connected at the same time to the encoder?

Comment: @glen_geek Fall time 1x 2.2ms Fall time 10x 12.8ms and I did do the probe calibration, the fall time when its on the siggen is 20us

Comment: @DavideAndrea I cant use the fluke probes on the Rigol, they use a different plug. Rigol is a BNC, and the Fluke is some kind of plug and I don't have an adapter

Comment: @rdtsc the rounded off wave is worse in 10x

Comment: "Worse with 10X" - that's worrying. If anything should be same or faster with 10X probe. Nevertheless, the noisyness of RIGOL suggests a more-true result. Could be that FLUKE sampling is too slow. Can you try triggering the FLUKE on falling-edge, and speed up the timescale to fill more of the screen with just that one falling edge?

Comment: @glen_geek Unfortunately the keypad on the fluke is non-functioning, we cant change any settings on it what so ever.

Comment: @BenderBending From the images I can find, the Fluke probes (VPS200) appear to use a push-on BNC. Are you sure they don't fit in the rigol scope?

Comment: @Hearth Yes, it does not fit

Comment: @glen_geek I added a third photo with a 10x example on the Rigol

Comment: If the fall time is lower on 10x setting than 1x, it means the encoder output is floating, and scope discharges to ground faster on 1x setting. Now, to verify that, which exact probe model you have on Fluke, on Rigol, and which exact encoder you have and what circuitry is connected to it?

Comment: This actually seems like the most likely culprit. Yes, the encoder is floating. I'll try to ground it and see if that works.

Comment: @Justme Very astute. Either a pulldown resistor is missing because the cable from encoder-to-microcontroller has been pulled out, or else oscilloscope GND is going to wrong place (perhaps LED current source?). I calculate from RC time constant that one-to-two nanofarads is involved. That's more than probe loading, so it'd be a physical capacitor somewhere.

Comment: @glen_geek That was exactly the problem. We failed to identify a pull down resistor on the bench that the fluke is reading. We added the pull down resistor to the rigol bench and its working perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, set your probe to x10. The x1 setting on a probe is rarely used as x10 can be accounted for on modern oscilloscopes. x1 setting on a passive probe has a lower input impedance, compared to a x10 setting, which will therefore give a less accurate reading for you. Your Rigol scope should have a higher sample rate, meaning it can observe the rising or falling edges of your signal much easier. Your rotary encoder will have a rise and fall time - even if it is nearly non-observable. Does it matter that fall time is present? If not, I guess this is an educational question. If it it a problem, I'd suggest reviewing your schematic or whatever it's connected to. Have a look at these references, they will help hopefully. https://www.omch.co/incremental-rotary-encoder/
https://youtu.be/nLmB1qcXT4Q https://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/probes-x1-or-x10/